# Running a php application alongside a rails application

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, session, nginx

I have an application that some parts have been written in Ruby and few parts in PHP ,some links transfer you to a rails application while others to the PHP application,  the rails application runs on nginx while PHP runs on apache ,the sessions, however, is managed by the rails application ,my problem is when you log out of the rails application the PHP links are still accessible,  how do I manage sessions so that when someone logs out of the rails application you are logged out of the php application as well.

Comment: you can make column in db islogin when someone login from php or rail set it to 1 and when logout set it to 0

Comment: If the rails app handles the authentication, create an API which PHP can call and check the authentication status.

Comment: @AmitBisht kindly elaborate

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ,seems like quite elegant solution ,what if the php code is not written on a framework ?

Comment: That doesn't matter. A framework is basically just a bunch of wrappers/ready made functions for common tasks. It's not like you _must_ use a framework. Nothing is stopping you to write those functions yourself. You can also include some tried and tested libraries in your code to make it easier.

Comment: @DuncanAceAkello i was saying first create a column `isLogin` in users table or whatever the table name and when someone login set that to `1` and when some one logout set that to `0` and when you are checking session exists or not also check is `isLogin` is 1 If it is let user logged in other wise log them out and also remember set that column value by default to `0`